# How Makefile split string into individual words?

Tags: makefile

I write a `Makefile` like this:

```
all:
    @echo $(wildcard $(include)/*.sh)
    @echo $(include)

.PHONY:all
```

I input `make "include=~"` and output is

```
/home/ubuntu/caps_esc.sh /home/ubuntu/ss.sh
/home/ubuntu
```

But when inputing `make "include=~ "`(note the white space!) the output is

```
/home/ubuntu
/home/ubuntu
```

which means that the variable `include` is `~` plus white space.
So my question is, How Makefile split string into individual words?

Answer (score 1):

Make uses whitespace to separate tokens, the extra space results in `$(wildcard ~ /*.sh)` which gives the `wildcard` function two tokens, `~` and `/*.sh`, rather than a single token `~/*.sh`.

Make will only trim whitespace in certain circumstances, you should read the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for details.